# least square optimization with more than two arguments

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, least-squares

I have a data frame of three columns, one is bond maturity time, coupon value and market asked value while all bond don't have the same times interval and coupon pay twice a year, I am trying to fit a 4th degree polynom to fit the rate interest in the market. while the real value of the bond are in the asked column 
I tried this and it keep faling can you please help:

```
#tzvika and brothers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import leastsq as lsq
df=pd.read_csv('bonds2.csv')
#today=pd.datetime.today()
today=pd.to_datetime('2018-03-28')
def rate(alpha,time):
    power=4-np.arange(5)
    return (alpha*time**power).sum()

#caluclate the present value of
def value_of_flow(alpha,maturity,coupon):
    '''if today>pd.to_datetime(maturity):
        #raise Exception('The bond is off date.')
        return -1'''
    today=pd.to_datetime('2018-03-23')
    maturity=pd.to_datetime(maturity)
    coupon_paying_dates=pd.date_range('{}/{}/{}'.format(today.year-1,maturity.month,maturity.day),maturity,freq='12SM-15')
    coupon_paying_dates=coupon_paying_dates[coupon_paying_dates>today]
    day_interval=(coupon_paying_dates-today).days/365

    pv=0
    r_t=0
    period=0
    for period in day_interval:
        r_t=rate(alpha,period)
        pv+=coupon*0.5*np.exp(-r_t*period)

    #get the rate in the last period to calculate present value of face value
    r_t=rate(alphas,day_interval[-1])
    pv+=1*np.exp(-r_t*day_interval[-1])
    return pv
def Errorfun(alpha,maturity,coupon,asked):
    return value_of_flow(alpha,maturity,coupon)-asked
today=pd.to_datetime('2018-03-23')
alphas=np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])
alphas_value,success=lsq(Errorfun,alphas,args=(df.Maturity,df.Coupon,df.Asked))
```

I keep getting this error:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'month'
> ```

while if I run other code on the maturity column it run smooth